# Installing R Package FeatureHashing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation

When I issue the command:

`install.packages("FeatureHashing")`

the source is downloaded and unzipped properly but then a whole lot of compilation errors occur, starting with:

```
as.cpp: In function ‘void pair_sort(int*, double*, std::size_t)’:
as.cpp:26:83: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
   std::sort(ref.begin(), ref.end(), [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return i[a] < i[b]; });
                                                                               ^
as.cpp:26:84: error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(std::vector<long unsigned int>::iterator, std::vector<long unsigned int>::iterator, pair_sort(int*, double*, std::size_t)::<lambda(std::size_t, std::size_t)>)’
   std::sort(ref.begin(), ref.end(), [&](size_t a, size_t b) { return i[a] < i[b]; });
```

As suggested on Wush Wu's GitHub Issue page relating to a problem installing under RedHat:

https://github.com/wush978/FeatureHashing/issues/116

I installed gcc 4.8 and g++ 4.8

What do I need to do for the installation to succeed?

Comment: What's the actual `g++` command line leading up to this error? Did you try `-std=c++11` like it says in the error message?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I should try -std=c++11  but I don't know how to do this. Where do I find the makefile?

Comment: Not really familiar with the platform, but http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#make indicates that you might be able to put something in `Makevars`.

Comment: Thanks. I copied Makeconf to Makevars and edited Makevars to make CC=gnu++11 but it didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't look right. The `CXX_STD` assignment in the existing `Makevars` is probably correct but you might want to try adding `PKG_CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11` although `CXX_STD=CXX11` might already be saying the same thing.